# How to have a radio checked on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, shopify, liquid

I have a donation page using Liquid Shopify. I CANNOT change **`name="donation[amount_option]"`** (I do not have access to that file) so I need code that allows this to stay.

*I want to have **$250** automatically checked on load*

My code

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="donation[amount_option]"][value=250]').checked = true;
```

```html
<div class="radio-inline donation-v2-amounts padbottommore">
  <span>
    <input id="donation_amount_25" type="radio" name="donation[amount_option]" class="donation_amount_option" value="25">
    <label for="donation_amount_25" class="radio">$25</label>
  </span>
  
  <span>
    <input id="donation_amount_250" type="radio" name="donation[amount_option]" class="donation_amount_option" value="250">
    <label for="donation_amount_250" class="radio">$250</label>
  </span>
  
  <span>
    <input id="donation_amount_1000" type="radio" name="donation[amount_option]" class="donation_amount_option" value="1000">
    <label for="donation_amount_1000" class="radio">$1,000</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your first paragraph saying you do not have the ability to change the html directly at all?  There appears to be some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a pure `js` alternative (in addition to the answer above). You can select by value:

`document.querySelector('input[value="250"]').checked = true;`

EDIT:

In case it isn't clear, you can use any valid selector such as the id, i.e.:

`document.querySelector('#donation_amount_25').checked = true;`.

Comment: Why not use the id?

Comment: THANKS! I was relying on another post that said I ALSO needed the name for the querySelector.

Comment: @SnowboardBruin no, you don't "need" anything specifically.  Just a valid selector, which can be anything.  My point of using the id, insteaed of the value attribute as this answer suggests, is that ids are indexed, and are faster lookups.

Comment: Of course you can use the id. Choosing the value attribute is purely arbitrary.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#donation_amount_250').prop('checked',true);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add the "checked" keyword to the end of the input.

```
<input id="donation_amount_250" type="radio" name="donation[amount_option]" class="donation_amount_option" value="250" checked>
```

Comment: The user explicitly states in the first paragraph they do not have access to that file

Comment: @Taplar the user states the name cannot change.

Comment: Followed by the parenthesis saying they cannot access that file

Comment: Meaning that the name is used by another file that he does not have access to, that's they way it is worded. It literally says "My code", which would mean access is available.

Comment: That was at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: The edit history disagrees with you.  "My code" has always been there.

Comment: Correct, the javascript was at the very bottom included with the rest of "My Code".

Comment: I've made a comment on the OP for clarification.  We can determine who misread the question through them.